# Do Python functions copy the input parameters to the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, timeit

I have the following example in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

# array size
m = 3000

# square array
a = np.random.rand(m, m)

# column vector
b = np.random.rand(m)

# solve
ti = timeit.default_timer()
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
tf = timeit.default_timer()

# solve function
def solver(a, b):
    x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
    return x

tii = timeit.default_timer()
x = solver(a, b)
tff = timeit.default_timer()

print('time1 ', tf-ti)
print('time2 ', tff-tii)
```

The time comparison for not using a function (time1) vs using a function (time2) is:

```
time1  0.6199771239989786
time2  0.5945519460001378
```

There seems to be a slight difference between in the two approaches. How are the input parameters handled for the function `solver`, are they copied or are they just passed to the internals of the function?

Comment: what happens to the timing if you run the tests in the opposite order?

Comment: @AShelly well that's interesting, if I run the tests in the opposite order the times are switched

Comment: oh yes, without an additional function call it is slower ;-) Sure, before the first call, there are some initializations to be done.

Comment: No copy is made, for sure, numpy arrays are passed as pointers. You can check with the memory profiler, or more ad hoc by initializing an `a` that uses more than half of your memory and see that it doesn't crash, at least before the solver is invoked

Comment: Very interesting, the reversal -- that points to some initialization overhead. But in any case, are the two time values really statistically different from each other? What are the standard errors on each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed difference is likely due to some memory caching of the contents of `a` and `b`  that the second call to `linalg.solve` takes advantage of.

And to answer the question, objects in python are passed by reference, so the only differencein the cost of passing arguments is that you are doing it twice in the 2nd example.  But that is probably a tiny fraction of the solve cost.

Comment: I expect flameware here :)

Comment: So for larger projects, passing data to a function declared in another file should not adversely affect the overall computation time compared to doing everything in the same file?

Comment: If you are very picky, doing the attribute lookup and changing scopes when entering functions does add some overhead (ns range, though).